# Rotate/Resize Controls behave unexpectedly when JQueryUI widgets are used with Fabric.js

Tags: jquery-ui, fabricjs

I just discovered Fabric.js and though the documentation is a lacking a bit, it seems like it will handle everything I need for an HTML-based Dream Board tool I'm building.  It appears that it doesn't play well with JQueryUI, though.

When I set any of my objects to be JQueryUI widgets, button, dialog box, etc...the control handles seem to be non responsive on the top half of my canvas items, and even on the bottom, the hit areas for resizing/rotating are greatly reduced, which makes the items hard to manipulate. Has anyone run into this? Is this a known issue? I checked github and have tried to search SO to no avail.

Thank you!

http://seismicdevelopment.com/test/no-jquery-uis.html - No JQuery UI Widgets...behaves how I'd expect.

http://seismicdevelopment.com/test/with-jquery-uis.html - Click 'Add Image', you'll get an image, but compared to the other page, you'll notice that the corners of the image aren't as interactive...you can move the image ok, but rotating and scaling is ver hit-or-miss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in offsets. jQueryUI is probably modifying height of those buttons, which moves canvas slightly down, comparing to how it was during initialization.

I explained this — and why it happens in Fabric — in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179754/130652).