# Why doesn't fabricjs canvas update properly after object.center()?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

1. Add an object to a fabric canvas
2. call object.center()
3. error: http://jsfiddle.net/tBnfL/

It seems the object is now in two places. It's visually rendered in the center, but the mouse cursor sees it as in its original position. If you click on the original position, the canvas updates properly and things behave as normal.

`canvas.calcOffset()` doesn't fix it (as it did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100878/fabricjs-canvas-is-stuck-after-adding-elements)).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out this is an open issue in fabricjs:

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/642

The solution is to call `object.setCoords()` after changing the object's position.

Comment: Thanks! Great & Easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

The above has not worked for me, but the following code works fine

```
canvas.renderAll();
```