# How do i update filters for images inside a group in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, grouping, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a layer-function with grouped images of the same size. If i add a filter on one of the images in the group nothing happens. But i found out that if i add a shadow on the group object, it will force an update on all items inside the group. 
Is there another way to force this update on the group items?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100878/fabricjs-canvas-is-stuck-after-adding-elements#11179754

Comment: It doesn't seem to help my problem. The positioning and layering of the group items works fine. The only problem is with applying filters to image-items.

Comment: - sorry, the applying of the filters works but it's not visually updated...